# Styled Select Tags with optgroups look different in Firefox 40

Tags: css, firefox, select

If you have a global font-family style on select tags, Firefox from version 40 will render them different if they have optgroups inside or not.
In older versions the appearance is similar.

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyn56n6n/2/) to demonstrate the effect. Just try this demo in FF40 and in an older version.

```
<style type="text/css">
    select { font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }
</style>

<select>
    <optgroup label="Group1">
        <option value="1">Option 1 Group 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2 Group 1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group2">
        <option value="3">Option 3 Group 2</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4 Group 2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

It seems that the new version has a different font-family priority when rendering selects with optgroups.

Is this a bug? Or does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the wildcard selector?

```
* {
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: That works, but maybe I don't want to style any tags.
So I just included **optgroup** and **option** in my style, now the styling is the same like in older versions.

`select, optgroup, option {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Firefox uses the :before pseudo class to style optgroup labels

```
optgroup:before {
    content: attr(label);
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
}
```